# Postgres Service cannot restart after crash (Killed by OOM)

Tags: postgresql, debian

I use below Postgres on my Debian.

```
PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
```

Sometimes OOM kill Postgres process. here is a log of what happened:

```
/var/log/syslog:Jun 28 04:18:09 dashboard03 kernel: [17747145.470355] Out of memory: Killed process 3680079 (postgres) total-vm:60173160kB, anon-rss:2644kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:32631780kB, UID:107 pgtables:76056kB oom_score_adj:0
```

The problem is Postgres cannot start automatically after crash. Here is Postgres log:

```
2023-06-28 04:18:09.891 UTC [3680076] LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 3680079) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [3680076] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [4109121] ehsan@dashboard WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [4109121] ehsan@dashboard DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the cu>
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [4109121] ehsan@dashboard HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat>
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [275401] ehsan@dashboard WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [275401] ehsan@dashboard DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the cur>
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [275401] ehsan@dashboard HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat >
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [114738] ehsan@dashboard WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [114738] ehsan@dashboard DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the cur>
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [114738] ehsan@dashboard HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat >
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [3680082] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [3680082] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transactio>
2023-06-28 04:18:09.917 UTC [3680082] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2023-06-28 04:18:10.162 UTC [1907896] ehsan@dashboard FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2023-06-28 04:18:11.191 UTC [3680076] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2023-06-28 04:18:17.286 UTC [3680076] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-06-28 04:18:17.287 UTC [1907912] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-06-28 04:15:38 UTC
2023-06-28 04:18:17.364 UTC [1907913] ehsan@dashboard FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2023-06-28 04:18:17.365 UTC [1907914] ehsan@dashboard FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2023-06-28 04:18:17.484 UTC [1907912] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-06-28 04:18:17.514 UTC [1907912] LOG:  redo starts at 46C/93DCE1A8
2023-06-28 04:18:17.516 UTC [3680076] LOG:  abnormal database system shutdown
2023-06-28 04:18:17.678 UTC [3680076] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I checked `restart_after_crash` parameter and value is `on`

Why Postgres cannot restart automatically after such this crash? while I can start it manually.
What I missed to configure to restart Postgres after crash?

Here logs when i started it manually with `sudo service postgresql start`:

```
2023-06-28 04:26:22.605 UTC [1909598] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-0+deb11u1) on x86>
2023-06-28 04:26:22.606 UTC [1909598] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-06-28 04:26:22.606 UTC [1909598] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.>
2023-06-28 04:26:22.649 UTC [1909600] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 20>
2023-06-28 04:26:22.649 UTC [1909600] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and yo>
2023-06-28 04:26:22.653 UTC [1909601] ehsan@dashboard FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2023-06-28 04:26:22.653 UTC [1909602] ehsan@dashboard FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2023-06-28 04:26:22.762 UTC [1909600] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic r>
2023-06-28 04:26:22.765 UTC [1909600] LOG:  redo starts at 46C/93DCE1A8
2023-06-28 04:26:22.841 UTC [1909600] LOG:  invalid record length at 46C/94EF5338: wanted 24, got 0
2023-06-28 04:26:22.841 UTC [1909600] LOG:  redo done at 46C/94EF5300
2023-06-28 04:26:23.089 UTC [1909598] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

It seems DB recovered very fast.

Here are systemd file content in `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service`:

```
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
AssertPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service
# stop server before networking goes down on shutdown
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
# -: ignore startup failure (recovery might take arbitrarily long)
# the actual pg_ctl timeout is configured in pg_ctl.conf
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
# 0 is the same as infinity, but "infinity" needs systemd 229
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
TimeoutStopSec=1h
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-900
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: A terminated program cannot magically restart itself, because it's terminated (i.e. not running anymore). You have to configure some external monitor, such as `systemd`, to do that.

Comment: Sorry for my poor descriptions. I start it with ```sudo service postgresql start``` so i guess it is a service with default configurations.

Comment: `terminated program cannot magically restart itself` - but the parent process can. Just what happens with postgresql: there is a parent process and there are N forks. OOM has a very low chance of killing the parent postgres process, it consumes almost no memory. But in case of an abnormal interruption of the child process, postgres restarts the entire database.

Comment: the database restart has started, but someone external asked it to be interrupted: `received fast shutdown request`. Check if you have some kind of timeout configured for the service start time (this is not a postgresql setting)

Comment: @Melkij I added some more info. after I started service manually. it seem it recovered very fast, not sure any timeout happened. I added service file too. all configs in service is as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system was presumably in a poor state at the time OOM kicked in--that is why it kicked in.  It wouldn't be surprising if recovery was slow, as things might have been swapped out which then need to be swapped back in.  When you start it again manually later, things are in a better state so it is not surprising it would go faster.  This doesn't explain who commanded the recovery to abort in the first place, but does explain why recovery might be faster when it is manually tried again later.

You should focus on who commanded the fast shutdown during recovery, not how long recovery is taking the second time you try it.

**Edit**

For what it is worth, I can reproduce this trivially both with Debian and Ubuntu, with the PostgreSQL installed with apt and the systemd files provided by that.  After provoking OOM killer, PostgreSQL automatically restarts, but then immediately gets told to shutdown.  The only thing that could be signaling it is the systemd system itself. This only happens with OOM; if I manually kill -9 a backend process, then PostgreSQL successfully restarts.

On a t2.micro machine, it can be reproduced just by doing:

```
set work_mem TO "80GB";
select * from generate_series(1,10000000) order by random();
```

I'm not a systemd lawyer.  I have no idea why it would do this, but I would have to guess it is doing it intentionally.

You can prevent the OOM killer by [disabling memory overcommit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html).  But on the t2.micro doing that renders the machine unusable, as memory is oversubcribed right out of the box due to snapd, packagekit, and other bloatware.

Comment: You're right. No one have access that server for sure except me. I have no idea which script can abort restarting. Should I start with increasing ```TimeoutStartSec``` in ```postgresql@.service``` file?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes . I'm not sure but seems receiving fast shutdown request after initialization is normal. [link](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/kb/articles/postgress-fast-shutdown-initialization/)

Comment: I uncommented ```Restart=on-failure``` in unit file and  auto restart work now. I'm just worry about this comment in unit file: ```# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,```.

Comment: @A.F.N  That link is not very informative.  It just says it is "normal", which I guess it is because apt is popular and it happens with apt's supplied unit files, so that makes it normal.  But that is not how it works if you just start PostgreSQL manually or with a simple command `pg_ctl start` in /etc/rc.local, for example.  And it seems undesirable to me